# Issue with displaying PHP code in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am using a slider in one HTML page and sending its value to the next page using a hidden textbox like this :

Page1.html

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var flowPercent = document.querySelector('#flow');
      function sliderFunc()
      {
        var f = function(){
          var x = flowPercent.value;
          window.open('Page3.html?val=x','_parent');
      };
      f();

    };
      </script>
```

And then I would like to display this in the next HTML page using PHP echo like this :

```
<?php
          $val=$_POST['val'];
          echo "Value is $val";
          ?>
```

But neither the value nor "Hello" is being displayed. Why is this ?
How do I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: where is your form tag? what is your method? get or post?

Comment: Web server just get `Page3.html` from filesystem not through php. Try to name it `Page3.php` or better way configure webserver to execute `.phtml` ext in php and name it `Page3.phtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP-Code is contained in Page3.html, that page should have a .php-extension in order to execute the code. And also you are not posting anything, so `$_POST` will be useless...

Try `window.opener.getElementById('textbox')` instead to query the value...

Comment: Yes the file extension was indeed the issue. How do I get the value of the textbox in Page2 ? I cannot use the getElementbyId method that you said as the textbox would be undefined in the next screen. How do I do this ?

Comment: Did you try my suggested code? `window.opener` should give a link to the original window that contained the textbox, so I would expect that to work...

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail ? I didn't quite understand where exactly to use the code you have specified. Is this in Page1 or Page3 ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was too short and a bit stupid, too ;-)  I guess it would be better to pass that name in the URL you are calling, so in Page1.html use  `window.open('Page3.php?page='+x);`

Comment: Hi. Please check the updated question ? It still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: 2 things: in Page1, use `window.open('Page3.html?val=' + x,'_parent');` to append the value of x, and in page 3, use `$_GET['val']`to query the value.

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly now :). One last question, how do I make the query string more secure so user's are not able to view the values being sent ? Thanks again !

Comment: You could use some sort of encoding and add some 'secret ingredients' in order to avoid tampering of URLs. But for ultimate security, I'd recommend to go away from GET and generate POST-Variables by submitting the page...

Answer (score 1):

Just change your page3.html to page3.php because you can't use php code in html file but you can use html code in php

Comment: @Shivam Bhalla let me know if it is works for you :)

Comment: @Shivam Bhalla plz accept the answer,so that other also find useful this post